# How to create an object in Django Rest Framework that is related to other models

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have 3 models: user, barber and booking. In my `createBooking` view, I am having trouble to figure out how to pass the IDs of the user and the barber. Here's my code:

The view:

```
def createBooking(request):
    data = request.data
  
    booking = Booking.objects.create(
        barber_id = data['barberb_id'],
        customer_id = data[ 'customer_id'],
        timeslot = data['timeslot'],
        )
    serializer = BookingSerializer(booking, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The booking model:

```
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    barber_id = models.ForeignKey(Barber, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    timeslot = models.DateTimeField('appointment')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customer_id} {self.barber_id} {self.timeslot}"
```

With the current code, I'm getting the error `Cannot assign "['customer_id']": "Booking.customer_id" must be a "User" instance.`

Answer (score 0):

since you already gave attribute name as barber_id and customer_id in model you will have to create object as below.

```py
 booking = Booking.objects.create(
        barber_id_id = data['barberb_id'],
        customer_id_id = data[ 'customer_id'],
        timeslot = data['timeslot'],
        )
```

Even though we don't give the suffix `_id` at the end, the foreign keys are stored with `attribute_name` + `_id`. We can directly use it in django as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can define model as below for the user related and try by passing user instance to customer_id.

```
customer_id = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name='%(class)s_customer_id')
    
Basically it should be an user instance.  
   
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.get(id=data['customer_id'])
booking = Booking.objects.create(
            barber_id = data['barberb_id'],
            customer_id = user,
            timeslot = data['timeslot'],
            )
```